# How to make tags in email template editor clear to all users?

Tags: email, templates, text-editor, code

I'm working on a web application where users (of an organization) can edit email templates. For example, one template would be used to confirm an appointment (that a client has made with the organization).

The user should place tags (like `{appointmentDate}` and `{appointmentTime}`) in the template. When the message is sent, the tags are replaced by the actual content.

How can the editor be designed to be as simple as possible, even for non-technical users?

Comment: Have you seen how automation recipes on ifttt.com can be created? They have exactly this kind of implementation and I think the design/interaction would work great for your case.

Comment: @Erion Thanks. I took a look at the email action (which send a message) and they have a pretty nice editor indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions would be to style the tags as soon as they're typed.

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438371/style-text-inside-textarea-like-facebook-does) has some details on how to do that.

As for initial explanations; try buttons like the bold/italic/link/image input buttons above the text field.

It's either that, or use a legend.

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple. Provide drag and drop or insert functionality to the user. you can use simple words like insert Appointment date or time or provide a place/template where user would be able to drag and drop time and date icons on the canvas.
I am attaching a sample wire-frame for reference:

[image]